# Python/wxPython: How to reset wx.Choice to a default value

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Am working with multiple wx.Choice control in wxPython and I needed the make a reset button to restore the default option “-- Select --” when clicked.
Am unable to achieve that, the closest I came is to reset to empty options which is NOT what is want. I want the default option “-- Select --” to come up when reset button is pressed. See my code below.

**data.py**

```
import wx

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 250,300 ), style = wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        DataBox = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        gSizer2 = wx.GridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )

        self.Color_Label = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Color:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.Color_Label.Wrap( -1 )
        self.Color_Label.SetFont( wx.Font( 13, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        gSizer2.Add( self.Color_Label, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        Color_optionsChoices = [ u"-- Select --", u"Red", u"Green", u"Pink", u"Blue", u"Yellow", u"White", u"Brown" ]
        self.Color_options = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, Color_optionsChoices, 0 )
        self.Color_options.SetSelection( 0 )
        gSizer2.Add( self.Color_options, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Age = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Age:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.Age.Wrap( -1 )
        self.Age.SetFont( wx.Font( 13, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        gSizer2.Add( self.Age, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        Age_optionsChoices = [ u"-- Select --", u"15", u"16", u"17", u"18", u"19", u"20", u"21", u"22", u"23", u"24", u"25", wx.EmptyString ]
        self.Age_options = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, Age_optionsChoices, 0 )
        self.Age_options.SetSelection( 0 )
        gSizer2.Add( self.Age_options, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Country = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Country:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.Country.Wrap( -1 )
        self.Country.SetFont( wx.Font( 13, 70, 90, 90, False, wx.EmptyString ) )

        gSizer2.Add( self.Country, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        Country_optionsChoices = [ u"-- Select --", u"Mexico", u"Peru", u"India", u"USA", u"UK", u"Greece", u"Agentina", u"Greece", u"Brazil", u"Egypt" ]
        self.Country_options = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, Country_optionsChoices, 0 )
        self.Country_options.SetSelection( 0 )
        gSizer2.Add( self.Country_options, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Reset_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Reset", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer2.Add( self.Reset_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Exit_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Exit", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        gSizer2.Add( self.Exit_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        DataBox.Add( gSizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( DataBox )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Reset_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnResetButton )
        self.Exit_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExitButton )




    def OnResetButton( self, event ):

#       val = '-- Select --'  # NOT WORKING

        val = ' '  # THIS WORKS, BUT RESETS TO EMPTY CHOICE

        self.Color_options.SetLabel(val)
        self.Age_options.SetLabel(val)
        self.Country_options.SetLabel(val)


    def OnExitButton( self, event ):
        self.Close()







app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame1(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: When dumping code, its best to only dump a minimal example of the part of your code that is problematic, you're far more likely to get help that way

Comment: Can't you just call self.Age_options.SetSelection(0) in the OnResetButton handler or am I misunderstanding what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Calling "SetSelection(0)" did the magic. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please reduce your source code to a minimal runnable example (explained below).

**Answer**: I am amazed that `wx.Choice.SetLabel(' ')` does something useful. What you want to do instead is:

```
    self.Color_Options.SetStringSelection(val)
```

(see the [wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_item_container_immutable.html#afa3800ff87f00a47211c3ce206e7bc39) for `wxChoice/wxItemContainer`).

**Remark**: `u'--Select--'` is not `'--Select--'` in Python. As it happens, if the source encoding is set to `UTF-8`, wxPython will not complain and understand `str` encoden in UTF-8 as well as `u''`.

**Minimal runnable example**: As important as ever: Making your example as small as possible will teach you which parts are relevant for your question and which are not. In many cases, by writing the minimal example, I very often find the answer myself.

Minimising your example:

```
import wx

class MyFrame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        color_choices = [u"-- Select --", u"Red", u"Green", u"Pink", u"Blue", u"Yellow", u"White", u"Brown"]
        self.color_options = wx.Choice(pnl, wx.ID_ANY, choices=color_choices)
        self.color_options.SetSelection(0)

        self.reset_button = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_ANY, u"Reset")

        szmain.Add(self.color_options, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 4)
        szmain.Add(self.reset_button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 4)
        pnl.SetSizer(szmain)

        self.reset_button.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnResetButton )

    def OnResetButton(self, event):
        val = '-- Select --'  # NOT WORKING
        #  val = ' '  # THIS WORKS, BUT RESETS TO EMPTY CHOICE

        self.color_options.SetLabel(val)

app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame1(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. I will keep to that.

Comment: If **you** think an answer is correct for your question, you can accept it (check mark below upvote/downvote button).

Answer (score 0):

In the above answer by @nepix32, I suggest to use `self.color_options.SetSelection(0)` instead of `self.color_options.SetLabel(val)` which will reset the choice to the first option when you click the reset button. Hope it is useful to post here.
So, the function will look like below:

```
def OnResetButton(self, event):
    self.color_options.SetSelection(0)
```